# How to optimize my code so i can make it load correctly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I made this code, which actually works, but when i started to add more functions and stuff it stopped loading correctly. Sometimes is says that an array's item is undefined, and so on. And, when i was testing it part by part i noticed that when i put an alert between 2 modules it works, maybe because the alert helps the first part of the code end what it was doing, so the next module start correctly. I know this code may be not very optimized as well but this never happened to me so i wanted to know more about it.

```
function Coordinates (x, y){
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

function Line (nombre, status, size) {
  this.coordinates = [];
  this.nombre = nombre;

  this.setCoordinates = function(x, y){
    this.coordinates.push(new Coordinates(x, y));
  }

  this.status = status;
  this.size = size;

  this.setStatus = function(number){
    this.status = number;
  }

  this.getColor = function(){
    switch (this.status) {
      case 0:
        return "yellow";
        break;
      case 1:
        return "orange";
        break;
      case 2:
          return "green";
        break;
      case 3:
          return "red";
        break;
    }
  }
};

var linesArray = [];
linesArray.pop();//I don't know why, but sometimes there is an undefined object inside

try{
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = process;
  xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/raspizonasstatus.txt", true);
  xhr.send();

}catch(err){
  alert(err);

}finally{
  var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr2.onreadystatechange = process2;
  xhr2.open("GET", "http://localhost/raspizonascoordenadas.txt", true);
  xhr2.send();

}

function process(){
  if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    var resp = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var aux = 1;

    for(item in Object.keys(resp)){
      var keyName = "zona"+aux;

      linesArray.push(
        new Line(
          Object.keys(resp)[item],
          parseInt(resp[keyName].status),
          parseInt(resp[keyName].size)
        )
      );
      aux++;
    }

  }
}

function process2(){
  if (xhr2.readyState == 4) {
    var resp2 = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);

    for(item in Object.keys(resp2)){
      for(part in Object.keys(resp2[Object.keys(resp2)[item]])){

        linesArray[item].setCoordinates(
          parseInt(resp2[Object.keys(resp2)[item]][part]["x"]),
          parseInt(resp2[Object.keys(resp2)[item]][part]["y"])
        );
      }
    }
  }
}

//////////////////////////This alert is needed to make this code run(show the lines in the canvas)/////////////////////////
alert("SOMETHING");

$(function(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasOffset=$("#canvas").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var coordL = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
      coordL = 0;
      drawLinesRect(
        defineLinesRect(
            linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL].x,
            linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL].y,
            linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL+1].x,
            linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL+1].y,
            linesArray[i].size),
        linesArray[i].getColor());

        if(linesArray[i].coordinates.length > 2){
          var count = linesArray[i].coordinates.length - 2;

          for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
            coordL++;
            drawLinesRect(
              defineLinesRect(
                  linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL].x,
                  linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL].y,
                  linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL+1].x,
                  linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL+1].y,
                  linesArray[i].size),
              linesArray[i].getColor());
          }

        }
    }

    function drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,lineWidth,color){
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.lineWidth=lineWidth;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
        ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function drawLinesRect(LinesRect,color){
        var r=LinesRect;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.translate(r.translateX,r.translateY);
        ctx.rotate(r.rotation);
        ctx.rect(r.rectX,r.rectY,r.rectWidth,r.rectHeight);
        ctx.translate(-r.translateX,-r.translateY);
        ctx.rotate(-r.rotation);
        ctx.fillStyle=color;
        ctx.strokeStyle=color;
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();
    }

    function defineLinesRect(x1,y1,x2,y2,lineWidth){
        var dx=x2-x1;
        var dy=y2-y1;
        var lineLength = Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
        var lineRadianAngle = Math.atan2(dy,dx);

        return({
            translateX:x1,
            translateY:y1,
            rotation:lineRadianAngle,
            rectX:0,
            rectY:-lineWidth/2,
            rectWidth:lineLength,
            rectHeight:lineWidth
        });
    }

    function processAction(Line){
      switch (Line.status) {
        case 0:
          break;
        case 1:
          var r = confirm("some text");
          if (r == true) {

          }
          break;
        case 2:
            var r = confirm("some text");
            if (r == true) {
            }
          break;
        case 3:
            var r = confirm("some text");
            if (r == true) {
            }
          break;
      }
    }

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      var coordL = 0;

      for (var i = 0; i < linesArray.length; i++) {
        coordL = 0;
        drawLinesRect(
          defineLinesRect(
              linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL].x,
              linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL].y,
              linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL+1].x,
              linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL+1].y,
              linesArray[i].size),
          "transparent");

          if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){
            processAction(linesArray[i]);
            return;
          }

          if(linesArray[i].coordinates.length > 2){
            var count = linesArray[i].coordinates.length - 2;

            for (var j = 0; j < count; j++) {
              coordL++;
              drawLinesRect(
                defineLinesRect(
                    linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL].x,
                    linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL].y,
                    linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL+1].x,
                    linesArray[i].coordinates[coordL+1].y,
                    linesArray[i].size),
                  "transparent");
                  if(ctx.isPointInPath(mouseX,mouseY)){
                    processAction(linesArray[i]);
                    return;
                  }
            }
          }
      }
    }
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", handleMouseDown, false);

}); // end $(function(){});
```

Comment: When ever you are playing with `async` requests you need to take care the dependent scripts are executed only after the success of the asyc calls. So for now you can wrap up all the document.ready scripts into a function and call this function in your xhr success

Comment: Why dont you put all your code inside `$(function(){ ... })` ?

Comment: @Reddy Yes, you are right, i searched a little and found the onload function that i can put and it works well, i tried to use try-catch-finally but i had some issues, but now it works well. Thanks.

Comment: Glad you found your solution. Happy coding!!

Comment: I don't believe it will make any difference, but why have you used `break` after the `return` in your `this.getColor = function()`? It seems unnecessary as I thought that the return should be enough to end the function

Comment: @Philip Eagles Yes, that break does nothing, but it was autogenerated so i didn't care much about it.